# Azure iot sdk for node, Enrollment is showing error

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I am trying make a API call to Azure iot dps service for individual enrollment form postman but we are receiving, 504 Gateway Timeout.

Headers :

[image]  Authentication, and registration is removed for security reasons but were filled as well.

body:

[image]

are there any other thing needed to added in head or body ?

Comment: Are you invoking a direct method? What API operation call are you making against DPS?

Comment: Yes I am using direct API call, https://<hostname>./enrollments/<id>?api-version=2021-06-01. And all this is a PUT request.